# iOS - XCode 4.3 'variable' needs a method?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was just wondering about creating apps on iOS.

I found this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Articles/01_CreatingProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-TP40012323-CH3-SW3

Apple's small tutorial on getting started.

You see, after following the whole tutorial at the end, I tried to compile my project, when the project was about to be displayed this error appeared:

```
2012-09-03 10:05:46.201 HelloWorld[29361:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught    exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<HelloWorldViewController 0x6837c10>      setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c7022 0x1558cd6 0x13c6ee1 0x9bf022 0x930f6b 0x930edb 0x94bd50 0x23371a 0x13c8dea         0x13327f1 0x23226e 0xd81fc 0xd8779 0xd899b 0x37401 0x37670 0x37836 0x3e72a 0xf596 0x10274     0x1f183 0x1fc38 0x13634 0x12b1ef5 0x139b195 0x12ffff2 0x12fe8da 0x12fdd84 0x12fdc9b 0xfc65     0x11626 0x1c3d 0x1ba5)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

My guess is theres a connection I did wrong, but what?

I even copy pasted the last .m and .h they give you and still It wont compile.

Property 'variable' requires method 'setLabel' to be defined - use @synthetize

variable and setLabel are changed 6 times(different warnings).

What am I doing wrong?

-------Edit this is my viewcontroller.h

```
#import "HelloWorldViewController.h"

@interface HelloWorldViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel 
*label;

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation HelloWorldViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setTextField:nil];
[self setLabel:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

self.userName = self.textField.text;

NSString *nameString = self.userName;
if ([nameString length] == 0) {
    nameString = @"World";
}
NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
self.label.text = greeting;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

if (theTextField == self.textField) {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: You'll need to show how you are implementing or synthesizing label and set label in your HelloWorldViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an example for a version of XCode you don't have.

Later versions of XCode will synthesize properties automagically for you, older versions won't, they just throw an error.

You need to add the line

```
@syntheisze label = _label;
```

just after the line that looks like `@implementation HelloWorldViewController`.

Though I guess a better solution would be just to upgrade XCode :)

Comment: Thats the thing, I've got Version 4.3.3 (4E3002)

Synth should already by done automatically, shouldnt it?

Comment: No, the auto-synthesis didn't start until Xcode 4.4.  The note in the tutorial that says "Note: Earlier versions of Xcode add an @synthesize directive in the implementation block for each property you declare using the Control-drag approach. Because the compiler automatically synthesizes accessor methods, these directives are unnecessary. You may safely delete them." does not apply to you.  Put your `@synthesize label` back in your implementation file and you fill be fine.